# SQL Getting SUM total from different column names

Tags: sql

Hope anyone can assist

How would I get the SUM total for different names in one column

Need the total AMT_0 for

```
RUB_0 =(HEADING1 + HEADING2 + HEADING3 + HEADING4 + HEADING5)
```

Sample data:

```
AMT_0   RUB_0
14872   HEADING1
14872   HEADING2
27690   HEADING3
10800   HEADING4
10800   HEADING5
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [ask]. [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41739272/edit) you question to include the DDL of the relevant table, some sample data as DML, and desired results. Also, please add the tag for the RDBMS you are working with.

Comment: Is that sample data? What's the expected result? Can you show us your current query attemt. Also tag the dbms you're using.

Comment: Thanks guys will follow the instructions for my next post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be simple `SUM` aggeragte

```
select sum(AMT_0)
From yourtable 
Where RUB_0 in('HEADING1','HEADING2','HEADING3','HEADING4','HEADING5')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(AMT_0) as TotalSum
from MyTable
where RUB_0 in ('HEADING1' , 'HEADING2' , 'HEADING3' , 'HEADING4' , 'HEADING5')
```

?